# Google OAuth: App or Server?

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js, google-authentication

I'd like to implement Google OAuth. I'm a bit confused whether to have it implemented in the client (mobile app) side or the server side!!

Implementing it in the client side would mean shipping the key and secret in the app (which I want to avoid). However, if I do it in the server side, how do I send back the correct response to the client after a successful callback?

Also, what are the benefits of each  of the two implementations?

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail on your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about implementing the Google+ OAuth 2 authentication from a native mobile application (not a web view), then, what you need is to create an installed application client and a web application client in the google console. The first one is for your mobile application, and the second one for your server.

Here is the workflow I used for my application :

1. the mobile application gets the authorization code from google with the g+ sdk, using a scope containing the web application client id. That way, the server has the authorization to connect with google+.

   Your scope could look like something like this:

   ```
   String LOGIN_SCOPES =
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login " +
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
   String SCOPES = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + GOOGLE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:" + LOGIN_SCOPES;
   ```
2. the mobile application calls a server route with the authorization code and the proper redirect uri (the one associated with the installed app in google dev console which usually looks like this 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob').
3. the server gets the access token from google with the authorization code, secret id, application id, and the installed application redirect uri (if you use the web application one, it will fail with a redirect_uri_mismatch error).
4. the server does whatever it wants with the access token, creates a valid session and gives it to the application as a response to its request.

That way, you don't need to store anything on the client side. You still need to send the authorization code from the client to your server (preferably https), but this code can only be used one time and is immediately consumed by the server.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Let me go through it and I'll have more questions, maybe. :)

Comment: what would you do if you want to handle for both native mobile and web app as well?

Comment: I wrote an article about this : https://github.com/elcurator/android-google-plus-omniauth-tutorial if your server is written with rails maybe you can use it as an example for your application. To implement both the web and Android authentication, I would use the same callback route for both since it's the same principle behind.

Comment: The constraint that Passport can have only a single LocalStrategy kind of limits me. I want to have separate local strategies - one for mobile and another for web. I'm using nodejs